# Php file connects to a local SQL file offline.

Tags: php, mysql, local

Is it possible, in a php file, to connect to a local MSQL table file (.sql file exported with phpadmin) ?

Both of the files would be offline and the php file would be triggered by a flash app.

So in my local php file, instead of

```
$connection = mysql_connect("mysql***.perso", "user", "password") or die ("Couldn't connect to the server.");
```

it'd be something like :

```
$connection = mysql_connect('my-dbase.sql')
```

(note : my-dbase.sql would be in the same folder as the .php file)

Is it possible ?

I've tried :

```
// create connection
$connection = file_get_contents('mydb.sql'); 

// select database
 $db = mysql_select_db("dbase_name", $connect) or die ("Couldn't select database.");

// create SQL
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM meteo where temps = '$temps' AND username = '$username'";

// execute SQL query and get result
 $sql_result = mysql_query($sql, $connection) or die ("Couldn't execute query.");
```

But it's not working...

Comment: .sql file is not a SQL structure, it is just commands.

Comment: There is http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-driver.embedded-server-start.php which starts an emebedded mysql server - i.e. your php process itself would become more or less a mysql server - but that most likely doesn't solve your problem. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I would like to access a database table offline. I've tried with xml but I don't know how to do it (I've posted here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31106246/search-informations-in-a-xml-database )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Sql file is not the same thing as a SQL database. So no you cannot just place a .sql file into a directory and have it work. The Sql file is actually a human readable version of the sql database. It contains all the commands to create the database, but without a sql server a .sql file is fairly useless.

You need a sql server in order to use a sql database. It is possible to use a sql database and not be online (connected to the internet)but it's not something that would just work from a flash app. You'd need some user setup first. (WAMP, XAMP, etc) or something like nodejs.

Comment: Thank you. I will try with an xml file, but I don't know how to do it : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31106246/search-informations-in-a-xml-database